# x-frame-options header set but can stilll embed in iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, web-applications, header, x-frame-options

The x-frame-options header is confirmed as set to SAMEORIGIN, but when creating a simplistic local HTML file e.g.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Clickjack test page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Website is vulnerable to clickjacking!</p>
<iframe src="http://www.yoursite.com/sensitive-page" width="500" height="500"> 
</iframe>
</body> 
</html>
```

and attempting to embed the target page i'm able to do so without issue.

What could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you own the site? The tag "SAMEORIGIN" will allow iframe requests from itself.  

So if google.com had an iframe going to google.com with the header "SAMEORIGIN" the request would go through fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons I can think of:

1. Page is being loaded from the same origin, hence allowed.
2. "X-Frame-Options" or "SAMEORIGIN" is not spelled correctly and hence ignored.
3. Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors directive is more permissive and X-Frame-Options is ignored when it is set. If this is the case it should be blocked in IE which doesn't understand Content-Security-Policy.
4. Your browser is more lenient with local files.